# ng serve error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost

Tags: angular

I was getting this error:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

when running `ng serve`. After web lookup, the proposed answer to this problem is to run this command instead:

```
ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Unfortunately, the instructions came without explanation.

This works and the Angular project compiled successfully. I am not sure why. Can someone explain why this works and what has happened in the background? Thanks

Comment: is this your first attempt `ng serve`ing the application or was it working before on a normal `ng serve`?

Comment: This is my first attempt at ng serve

Comment: Have you looked at your system's hosts configuration?

Comment: yeah, it includes: 127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.1.1      router.hm and 127.0.0.1 My-MBP

Comment: @sanjihan I've this problem too and it seems like the port is not released, if you run it on a different port it works perfectly.

Comment: if you add an entry of localhost in host file then the issue goes

Comment: yes, in your host file you must have 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 8):

#### solution for Ubuntu users

`--host` option does not work until there is an explicit entry in `hosts` file for your Operating system. I solved it adding a host entry inside `hosts' file under` ~/etc/hosts` on ubuntu OS.

#### to edit `hosts` file

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts // you could use nano or something else as per your preferred editor
```

#### entry example inside hosts

[image: example Hosts snip]

Answer (score 7):

Hi I was having the same issue, my configuration is virtual host was not for localhost. At the same time this issue comes when there is conflict between your global Angular CLI version with local Angular CLI version.
I tried with ng serve --port 4200 --host 127.0.0.1 that works for me.

Thanks

Comment: I just had this issue, in my case it was caused by a wrong hosts file, where it did not have any "localhost 127.0.0.1" entries.

Answer (score 3):

The issue for me was the host entry:

Since I was on MAC 
I `cmd+space bar` type terminal
then

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

add the localhost entry
`^ + O to save`  and 
`^ + x` to exit

and then my problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who work with docker, I had this issue because my docker was stuck, reset the docker application and everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a corrupted 'hosts' file. A nightly update on my MAC OS caused it.
This error made no sense at first and all conditions were misleading:

1. I ran 'ng serve' all day without error until suddenly vscode
   started throwing that error late in the day!
2. I haven't updated the hosts file in a year.
3. cat /etc/hosts --> 127.0.0.1   localhost (NO ERROR!)
4. ls -rtl /etc --> hosts file modified in the morning!
5. vi /etc/hosts --> bunch of ASCII characters that were not visible using cat command were now visible and corrupted the file!
6. I deleted the unwanted characters and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the person who use windows.
I have the same problem in angular.

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt`.
2. Add `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` line
   **ex** :

```
    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #   127.0.0.1       localhost
    #   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1 localhost
```